# Exporting mysql table to xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml

How can I export the contents of a mysql table to xml using php? I need this to de done and later on use this xml in a javacript application. The table is pretty simple an ID that is auto incremented , a name , a number , and a timestamp. I am using XAMPP 1.7.4 [PHP: 5.3.5] . And another question... where will the xml file be stored after it is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a one-off operation and you are okay with doing it manually, [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) supports exports to various formats, including XML: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/export. You get to chose the location of resulting file.

If you have to do it programmatically, I suppose you'll have to run the [mysqldump with the --xml flag](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml) from your script and read the resulting file (I'm pretty sure that's what phpMyAdmin does). Use the `--tab` option or I\O redirecting to create dump files where you want them.

Comment: No this is not one time operation. It has to be done periodically.

Comment: @skywatcherisl: okay, then you'll have to just call the `mysqldump` like I described in my edit

Comment: what about this method? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html#outputxml

Comment: @skywatcherisl: nothing wrong with it if you are willing to manually create your XML. In this case the question is not about exporting a mysql table in XML, it's just about reading the values from mysql table and writing some values to xml, these tasks don't overlap

Comment: @skywatcherisl: I don't understand your question, those are different tasks that serve different purposes and can't be compared

Comment: Well the result is the same. The xml file with the same inforamtion inside. But which method should i choose? Exporting the table or reading it and then store values to the xml?

Comment: @skywatcherisl: it depends. Try using mysqldump and look at the result file. If you are okay with format of the dump, go with exporting. It's guaranteed to work on any table and not as error-prone as custom implementation. If you want some custom XML formatting and fine tuning of the result markup, store the values yourself.

Comment: I dont think i need any special formatting. I will try the mysqldump.

Comment: @skywatcherisl: feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you, and welcome to the site